# Определение момента затухания аудио через ffmpeg

Tags: аудио, ffmpeg

Здравствуйте!
Есть аудио треки разной длины в формате m4a. И есть библиотека ffmpeg для работы с медиа.
Многие треки имеют эффект "затухания" в конце, и надо определить в какой именно момент это происходит (определяется один раз и значение вносится в базу вместе с другой информацией о треке).
Т.е. надо каким-то образом определить что трек начинает затухать и его громкость достигла 30% по сравнению с общей громкости песни.
Можно ли это решить средствами ffmpeg и если да, то как именно?

Answer (score 1):

Не подскажу, умеет ли это ffmpeg. Но есть замечательные плагины для извлечения информации из аудио треков: [VAMP plugins](http://www.vamp-plugins.org/download.html). Использовал их для определения бита в музыке (начала тактов, четверти, bpm).

Обратите внимание на BBC Vamp Plugins и, в частности, Energy, Intensity и Peaks.

Comment: Пока интересует такая возможность в ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Начните с изучения [документации по фильтрам](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html). Фильтр, который умеет детектировать уровень аудио [есть](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volumedetect), но в текущем виде он практически бесполезен. Скорее всего придётся самостоятельно писать программу, которая или сможет выдать нужное или править фильтр, что бы он уже выдавал необходимые данные.